# SSRS 2008 Query Parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that needs to display accounting data from different locations or all locations.

Table_sales:

```
PartId    Rev     LocId
1         $10     1
2         $2      1
3         $5      2
```

Lets say the query is something basic like this to get all revenue:

```
SELECT SUM(rev) FROM Table_sales
```

If I want to be able to limit the report to a particular Location I would have to change it to:

```
SELECT SUM(Rev) FROM Table_sales WHERE LocId = @param
```

But if I did that how would I get all locations without having multiple queries?

FYI the SQL 2008 Filter option doesn't seem work on the actual query I am using since the actual query uses group by functions.

Also SSRS 2008 DataSet queries can be expressions, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: You want to "limit the report to a particular Location", but you also want to get "get all locations".  Can you clarify the apparent conflict of intention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the filter options or dataset queries you mentioned in SSRS 2008, but in some of the older versions of SSRS, I've seen stuff like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Rev) FROM Table_sales WHERE LocId = @param or 'All' = @param
```

I'm doubtful that it's the most efficient way to do this, but it allows you to have 1 query where you can select either all results (by passing the term 'All' as the parameter) or just the LocId's you want (by passing the appropriate LocId as the parameter).

Comment: This is what we usually do for cases like this.  You can also do something like WHERE LocId = COALESCE(@param, LocId) and pass null as your parameter for 'all' case... but I doubt either is noticably faster/more efficient.

Comment: Interesting idea on COALESCE - that hadn't occurred to me before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use that:

```
SELECT SUM(Rev) FROM Table_sales WHERE LocId IN (@param)
```

Comment: Does that handle the case where I want to get them all? Like I would pass a null parameter or a specific string like 'All' or something.